# Equivalent of "throw" in R

Tags: r, error-handling

How does one "throw" an error in R?  I have a function that takes a data frame and some column names and does stuff with them.  If the columns don't exist, I want the function to stop and to stop all functions depending on it.

I have looked at `recover` and `browse` and `traceback` but, well, they seemed to be close but not what I am looking for.

Comment: Right, recover, browser, and traceback are for debugging, while try/catch systems are for handling errors in production code.

Comment: I love it when question askers use the name of the function they're looking for multiple times in a question ;)

Comment: I think there is a reason this question has more upvotes than the top answer. Even though [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) is technically off-topic, it is that kind of excellently tight summary of an unfamiliar topic that Stack Overflow is famous for.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

See `help(tryCatch)`:

> Conditions are signaled by
>   '`signalCondition`'.  In addition, the
>   '`stop`' and '`warning`' functions have
>   been modified to also accept
>   condition arguments.

and later under 'See Also':

> '`stop`' and '`warning`' signal conditions, and '`try`' is essentially a
>    simplified version of '`tryCatch`'.

so you probably want `stop`.

Comment: That works perfectly.  R is so weird, through no fault of their own -- it was designed long before we ironed out good interpreted language design.

Comment: According to the authors, it was heavily influenced by Scheme, which is both old and good. R is 'lispy' but with funky data structures. The "interesting" parts in R is probably related to that a lot of conventions differs from other languages, notably the C-language family that it is syntactically close too. I would guess because the language was evolved by a bunch of statisticians that needed a good tool, rather than developers needing a good tool. Just the fact that the 'dot' is just a character took a long time to take in.

Comment: Some basic examples here would be great, not only have citations. Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23917007/54964

Comment: I came to this question when searching how to rethrow an error in R with a saner error message, but keeping the trace intact (as in, you execute `traceback()` after the error to see what went wrong). Using `stop` in `error` argument of `tryCatch` will mess up the trace. However, the `finally` argument will allow throwing an additional message and keep the trace useful. Not exactly on-topic, but, I feel, important enough to warrant a few minuses and a threat of moderation kicking this comment out of the window. :-)

Answer (score 65):

Simple example:

```
f <- function(a, b){ 

    if (a == 0){ 
            stop("error message")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23917007/54964 for variables in the error messages.

Answer (score 8):

Beyond the base functions that Dirk mentions:

The [R.oo package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.oo/index.html) has additional exception handling functionality, including a throw() function which is very useful.  You can catch exceptions with the usual try or trycatch functions:

```
> try(throw("Division by zero.")); print("It's ok!");
Error: [2009-10-22 10:24:07] Exception: Division by zero.
[1] "It's ok!"
```

You can read more about it here: http://www1.maths.lth.se/help/R/R.oo/

Comment: Hehe.  R isn't funky enough without OO?  

Sorry to be flip, and definitely thanks for the interesting answer, but I will go with plain old stop() above.

Comment: There's even more OO now.  :)

Comment: @ws. What's so funky about R? `plot` plots a function, `try` `stop` `warn` all work as you'd expect, and almost everything I want to do is a one-liner.

Comment: Often "power of one-liners" isn't a good metric for a language. For many of us readable, understandable code trumps fewer lines.

Indeed, much is unintelligible to me because I'm a beginner, and I try to calibrate expectations accordingly. But other languages make it fairly intuitive to go from 0 to getting stuff done.

R also seems to have developed a culture of clever, difficult to read one-liners. I would argue for a culture of maximally English-like code, which could often also be one-liners, like Ruby.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the function `stopifnot` is very convenient to implement sanity checks in your code. It takes in several logical expressions and returns an error if any of them evaluates to false.

Example:
To check if column 'c' exists in the dataframe 'df':

```
df <- data.frame(a = numeric(), b = numeric())
stopifnot(!is.null(df$c))
```

This will throw the following error:

```
Error: !is.null(df$c) is not TRUE
```

Comment: If you want to change the error message from the default one produced by `stopifnot`, you can wrap it with `tryCatch` as in:  ```tryCatch(error = function(cnd) "your message here", stopifnot(your_condition)```