# Exception handling in R

Tags: r, exception

Does anyone have examples/tutorials of exception handling in R? The official documentation is very terse.

Comment: This one is also a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12193779/2026975.

Comment: I found this blog post to be quite useful: [http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Besides Shane's answer pointing you to other StackOverflow discussions, you could try a code search feature. This original answer pointed to Google's Code Search has since been discontinued, but you can try

- *Github search* as e.g. in [this query for tryCatch in language=R](https://github.com/search?q=tryCatch+language%3AR&type=Code&ref=searchresults);
- *Ohloh/Blackduck Code search* eg [this query for tryCatch in R files](https://code.openhub.net/search?s=tryCatch&pp=0&fe=R&mp=1&ml=0&me=0&md=1&ff=0&filterChecked=false)
- the [Debian code search engine on top of the whole Debian archive](http://search.debian.net)

Just for the record, there is also `try` but `tryCatch` may be preferable.  I tried a quick count at Google Code Search but try gets too many false positives for the verb itself -- yet it seems `tryCatch` is more widely used.

Comment: Maybe this example could help: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/2026975](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/2026975)

Comment: A [Github search](https://github.com/search?q=tryCatch+language%3AR&type=Code&ref=searchresults) is probably a decent replacement for the defunct link.

Comment: All the links are broken.

Answer (score 63):

Basically you want to use the `tryCatch()` function.  Look at help("tryCatch") for more details.

Here's a trivial example (keep in mind that you can do whatever you want with an error):

```
vari <- 1
tryCatch(print("passes"), error = function(e) print(vari), finally=print("finished")) 
tryCatch(stop("fails"), error = function(e) print(vari), finally=print("finished"))
```

Have a look at these related questions:

- [Equivalent of "throw" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608130/equivalent-of-throw-in-r)
- [catching an error and then branching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158780/r-catching-an-error-and-then-branching-logic)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+trycatch](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D%20trycatch)

Answer (score 22):

This result from a related google search helped me: http://biocodenv.com/wordpress/?p=15.

```
for(i in 1:16){
result <- try(nonlinear_modeling(i));
if(class(result) == "try-error") next;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The function `trycatch()` is fairly straight forward, and there are plenty of good tutorials on that.  A excellent explanation of error handling in R can be found in Hadley Wickham's book [Advanced-R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html), and what follows is a **very** basic intro to `withCallingHandlers()` and `withRestarts()` in as few words as possible:

Lets say a low level programmer writes a function to calculate the absolute
value.  He isn't sure how to calculate it, but knows [how to construct an
error](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling) and
diligently conveys his naiveté:

```
low_level_ABS <- function(x){
    if(x<0){
        #construct an error
        negative_value_error <- structure(
                    # with class `negative_value`
                    class = c("negative_value","error", "condition"),
                    list(message = "Not Sure what to with a negative value",
                         call = sys.call(), 
                         # and include the offending parameter in the error object
                         x=x))
        # raise the error
        stop(negative_value_error)
    }
    cat("Returning from low_level_ABS()\n")
    return(x)
}
```

A mid-level programmer also writes a function to calculate the absolute value, making use of the woefully incomplete `low_level_ABS` function.  He knows that the low level code throws a `negative_value`
error when the value of `x` is negative and *suggests* an solution to the problem, by
establishing a `restart` which allows users of `mid_level_ABS` to control the
way in which `mid_level_ABS` recovers (or doesn't)  from a `negative_value` error.

```
mid_level_ABS <- function(y){
    abs_y <- withRestarts(low_level_ABS(y), 
                          # establish a restart called 'negative_value'
                          # which returns the negative of it's argument
                          negative_value_restart=function(z){-z}) 
    cat("Returning from mid_level_ABS()\n")
    return(abs_y)
}
```

Finally, a high level programmer uses the `mid_level_ABS` function to calculate
the absolute value, and establishes a condition handler which tells the
`mid_level_ABS` to recover from a `negative_value` error by using the restart
handler.

```
high_level_ABS <- function(z){
    abs_z <- withCallingHandlers(
            # call this function
            mid_level_ABS(z) ,
            # and if an `error` occurres
            error = function(err){
                # and the `error` is a `negative_value` error
                if(inherits(err,"negative_value")){
                    # invoke the restart called 'negative_value_restart'
                    invokeRestart('negative_value_restart', 
                                     # and invoke it with this parameter
                                     err$x) 
                }else{
                    # otherwise re-raise the error
                    stop(err)
                }
            })
    cat("Returning from high_level_ABS()\n")
    return(abs_z)
}
```

The point of all this is that by using `withRestarts()` and `withCallingHandlers()`, the function
`high_level_ABS` was able to tell `mid_level_ABS` how to recover from errors
raised by `low_level_ABS` error without stopping the execution of
`mid_level_ABS`, which is something you can't do with `tryCatch()`:

```
> high_level_ABS(3)
Returning from low_level_ABS()
Returning from mid_level_ABS()
Returning from high_level_ABS()
[1] 3
> high_level_ABS(-3)
Returning from mid_level_ABS()
Returning from high_level_ABS()
[1] 3
```

In practice, `low_level_ABS` represents a function that `mid_level_ABS` calls a
lot (maybe even millions of times), for which the correct method of error
handling may vary by situation, and choice of how to handle specific errors is
left to higher level functions (`high_level_ABS`).

Answer (score 7):

The restart function is very important in R inherited from Lisp. It is useful if you want to call some function in the loop body and you just want the program to continue if the function call collapses. Try this code:

```
for (i in 1:20) withRestarts(tryCatch(
if((a <- runif(1))>0.5) print(a) else stop(a),
finally = print("loop body finished!")), 
abort = function(){})
```