# How to catch an error/exception in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception handling in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r)

Does anyone have idea on how to catch an error or an exception in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r

Comment: For people like me who got here from Google, this was helpful: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912

Comment: For those finding this page, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) has a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Like Joshua said: use `tryCatch`.  Include an `error` argument, which should be a function accepting one parameter (the error, typically called `e`).

```
tryCatch(
  stop("you threw an error"), 
  error = function(e) 
  {
    print(e$message) # or whatever error handling code you want
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you mean by "catch".  Look at `tryCatch` and `withCallingHandlers`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `stop`?
This will allow you to catch exceptions that you define.