# How to use the tryCatch() function?

Tags: r, exception, try-catch, r-faq

I want to write code using `tryCatch` to deal with errors downloading data from the web.

```
url <- c(
    "http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html",
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz")
y <- mapply(readLines, con=url)
```

These two statements run successfully. Below, I create a non-exist web address:

```
url <- c("xxxxx", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz")
```

`url[1]` does not exist. How does one write a `tryCatch` loop (function) so that:

1. When the URL is wrong, the output will be: "web URL is wrong, can't get".
2. When the URL is wrong, the code does not stop, but continues to download until the end of the list of URLs?

Answer (score 922, accepted):

### Setting up the code

```
urls <- c(
    "http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html",
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz",
    "xxxxx"
)

readUrl <- function(url) {
    tryCatch(
        {
            # Just to highlight: if you want to use more than one
            # R expression in the "try" part then you'll have to
            # use curly brackets.
            # 'tryCatch()' will return the last evaluated expression
            # in case the "try" part was completed successfully

            message("This is the 'try' part")

            suppressWarnings(readLines(url))
            # The return value of `readLines()` is the actual value
            # that will be returned in case there is no condition
            # (e.g. warning or error).
        },
        error = function(cond) {
            message(paste("URL does not seem to exist:", url))
            message("Here's the original error message:")
            message(conditionMessage(cond))
            # Choose a return value in case of error
            NA
        },
        warning = function(cond) {
            message(paste("URL caused a warning:", url))
            message("Here's the original warning message:")
            message(conditionMessage(cond))
            # Choose a return value in case of warning
            NULL
        },
        finally = {
            # NOTE:
            # Here goes everything that should be executed at the end,
            # regardless of success or error.
            # If you want more than one expression to be executed, then you
            # need to wrap them in curly brackets ({...}); otherwise you could
            # just have written 'finally = <expression>' 
            message(paste("Processed URL:", url))
            message("Some other message at the end")
        }
    )
}
```

### Using the code

```
> y <- lapply(urls, readUrl)
This is the 'try' part
Processed URL: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html
Some other message at the end
This is the 'try' part
Processed URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz
Some other message at the end
This is the 'try' part
URL does not seem to exist: xxxxx
Here's the original error message:
cannot open the connection
Processed URL: xxxxx
Some other message at the end
```

### Investigating the output

```
> head(y[[1]])
[1] "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>R: Functions to Manipulate Connections (Files, URLs, ...)</title>"
[2] "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"
[3] "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\" />"
[4] "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.3/dist/katex.min.css\">"
[5] "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
[6] "const macros = { \"\\\\R\": \"\\\\textsf{R}\", \"\\\\code\": \"\\\\texttt\"};"

> length(y)
[1] 3

> y[[3]]
[1] NA
```

### Additional remarks

#### `tryCatch`

`tryCatch` returns the value associated to executing `expr` unless there's an error or a warning. In this case, specific return values (see `NA` above) can be specified by supplying a respective handler function (see arguments `error` and `warning` in `?tryCatch`). These can be functions that already exist, but you can also define them within `tryCatch()` (as I did above).

#### The implications of choosing specific return values of the handler functions

As we've specified that `NA` should be returned in case of error, the third element in `y` is `NA`.

Comment: You should use `paste0` for that!

Comment: `paste0()` *is* in base. Internally, both `paste()` and `paste0()` call `do_paste` in [paste.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/paste.c). The only difference is `paste0()` does not pass a `sep` argument.

Comment: @jthetzel + @seancarmody: sorry, true for R-2.15.1. I was running an outdated version of R (2.14.1) and back then there wasn't such a function. Very nice, IMHO that should have been the default behavior of `paste` right from the beginning

Comment: is `out` will be `NULL` if a `warning` is issued in the `tryCatch` in your example?

Comment: @RNA: actually, I think that's a little mistake in my code as there is no `out` defined in the scope of the `warning` function. Just by looking at it, I'm not sure what R will take as the value for `out` via lexical scoping. I'll check

Comment: @RNA: updated the answer. If you don't supply anything explicitly, the handler functions will return `NULL`. Returning `out` in the warning case didn't make any sense to me anyomre, so I changed it to `return(NULL)` just for illustrative purposes. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @Rappster: yeah, thanks. and could you explain the last line `return (out)`too? Isn't this similar situation to the `return` in the warning function?

Comment: I was wondering why my `error` bit was always being executed - curly braces fixed it!

Comment: How can I display a message if the try part was completed successfully please ?

Comment: @JulienNavarre: remember that the "try part" always returns the **last** object (currently `readLines(con=url, warn=FALSE)` which is the actual thing that could go wrong). So if you wanted to add a message, you would would need to stored the actual retun value in a variable: `out <- readLines(con=url, warn=FALSE)` followed by `message("Everything worked")` followed by `out` in order to make this the last object that is actually returned

Comment: How to preserve information on what went wrong?
error = function(cond) {
     message(cond) }
does not return the same amount of information that shows up without a trycatch. Anybody face this issue? How to print information of the line that caused the error.

Comment: Try `conditionMessage (cond)`. That's the actual error message as a character string.

Comment: Fantastic example and well documented. May I request all commenters on frivolous questions like `paste` / `paste0` to be deleted so that we do not crowd this section with irrelevant stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a (nice) way to use the same functionality for both "warning" and "error" case? Or do I have to replicate the code?

Comment: How to execute a command in `finally` only if there wasn't any error?

Comment: `finally` runs using `on.exit()` in `tryCatch`. This is handy for clean up tasks like closing connections, removing temporary files, restoring a state, etc. These are tasks you want to do regardless of if your code runs successfully. More information about this can be found here: [How and when should I use on.exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28300714/6382434)

Answer (score 184):

`tryCatch` has a slightly complex syntax structure. However, once we understand the 4 parts which constitute a complete tryCatch call as shown below, it becomes easy to remember:

**expr**: [*Required*] R code(s) to be evaluated

**error** : [*Optional*] What should run if an error occured while evaluating the codes in expr

**warning** : [*Optional*] What should run if a warning occured while evaluating the codes in expr

**finally** : [*Optional*] What should run just before quitting the tryCatch call, irrespective of if expr ran successfully, with an error, or with a warning

```
tryCatch(
    expr = {
        # Your code...
        # goes here...
        # ...
    },
    error = function(e){ 
        # (Optional)
        # Do this if an error is caught...
    },
    warning = function(w){
        # (Optional)
        # Do this if a warning is caught...
    },
    finally = {
        # (Optional)
        # Do this at the end before quitting the tryCatch structure...
    }
)
```

Thus, a toy example, to calculate the log of a value might look like:

```
log_calculator <- function(x){
    tryCatch(
        expr = {
            message(log(x))
            message("Successfully executed the log(x) call.")
        },
        error = function(e){
            message('Caught an error!')
            print(e)
        },
        warning = function(w){
            message('Caught an warning!')
            print(w)
        },
        finally = {
            message('All done, quitting.')
        }
    )    
}
```

Now, running three cases:

**A valid case**

```
log_calculator(10)
# 2.30258509299405
# Successfully executed the log(x) call.
# All done, quitting.
```

**A "warning" case**

```
log_calculator(-10)
# Caught an warning!
# <simpleWarning in log(x): NaNs produced>
# All done, quitting.
```

**An "error" case**

```
log_calculator("log_me")
# Caught an error!
# <simpleError in log(x): non-numeric argument to mathematical function>
# All done, quitting.
```

I've written about some useful use-cases which I use regularly. Find more details here: [Using tryCatch for robust R scripts](https://web.archive.org/web/20200729171137/https://rsangole.netlify.app/post/try-catch/)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: How to make `log_calculator` return the value?

Comment: @Julien, the last line of `expr` gets returned if there is no error.

Comment: Is it also possible to have a return different than NULL when the expression is executed correctly?

Answer (score 89):

R uses functions for implementing try-catch block:

The syntax somewhat looks like this:

```
result = tryCatch({
    expr
}, warning = function(warning_condition) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(error_condition) {
    error-handler-code
}, finally={
    cleanup-code
})
```

In tryCatch() there are two ‘conditions’ that can be handled: ‘warnings’ and ‘errors’. The important thing to understand when writing each block of code is the state of execution and the scope.
[@source](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912)

Comment: Replace `error-handler-code` with `cat("web url is wrong, can't get")`

Comment: you left out message-catching

Answer (score 69):

Here goes **a straightforward example**:

```
# Do something, or tell me why it failed
my_update_function <- function(x){
    tryCatch(
        # This is what I want to do...
        {
        y = x * 2
        return(y)
        },
        # ... but if an error occurs, tell me what happened: 
        error=function(error_message) {
            message("This is my custom message.")
            message("And below is the error message from R:")
            message(error_message)
            return(NA)
        }
    )
}
```

If you also want to capture a "warning", just add `warning=` similar to the `error=` part.

Comment: Should there be curly brackets around the `expr` part, since there are two lines instead of one?

Comment: Thanks! After double checking, I don't see any need for curly brackets

Comment: Thanks for double checking. When I run your code, I got `Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"` and `Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"`. Adding a pair of curly brackets solves the problem.

Comment: For most use cases, you are right, thank you! It has been fixed.

Answer (score 33):

Since I just lost two days of my life trying to solve for tryCatch for an irr function, I thought I should share my wisdom (and what is missing). FYI - irr is an actual function from FinCal in this case where got errors in a few cases on a large data set.

1. Set up tryCatch as part of a function. For example:

   ```
   irr2 <- function (x) {
     out <- tryCatch(irr(x), error = function(e) NULL)
     return(out)
   }
   ```
2. For the error (or warning) to work, you actually need to create a function. I originally for error part just wrote `error = return(NULL)` and ALL values came back null.
3. Remember to create a sub-output (like my "out") and to `return(out)`.

Comment: Why is number 3 necessary?

Answer (score 4):

The `purrr` package gives alternate functions that can be friendlier to set up than `tryCatch`. From the `?safely` documentation, they are described as:

- `safely`: wrapped function instead returns a `list` with components `result` and `error`. If an error occurred, `error` is an `error` object and `result` has a default value (`otherwise`). Else error is `NULL`.
- `quietly`: wrapped function instead returns a `list` with components `result`, `output`, `messages` and `warnings`.
- `possibly`: wrapped function uses a default value (`otherwise`) whenever an error occurs.

Note that these functions, unlike `tryCatch()`, are expected to wrap **a function**, not an expression, and they return a modified function.
For OP's problem as stated, we would probably use `possibly` and wrap `readLines` directly to modify it.

```
url <- c(
    "http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html",
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz", 
    "xxx")

library(purrr)
lapply(url, possibly(readLines, otherwise = "web URL is wrong, can't get"))
## with possibly, the error prints as a warning
## and the final value is the `otherwise` string
```

But also note that we could create a modified version of `readLines`, such as `my_readLines <- possibly(readLines, otherwise = "web URL is wrong, can't get")` that could be used in multiple places in our code.

I illustrate with `possibly` above, but we could easily imagine cases where we would want to use `safely()` (after which we could extract the `result` component from each list item, possibly skipping or otherwise handling items with a non-empty `error` component, perhaps even handling them differently based on the error), or `quietly` which also captures warnings and messages separately.