# Where does the 'e' or the 'c' come from in R's tryCatch

Tags: r, error-handling

I have been reading through the answers on SO about how to use `tryCatch`. I really don't understand where the `c` variable comes from though.

e.g. (via http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling)

```
show_condition <- function(code) {
  tryCatch(code,
    error = function(c) "error",
    warning = function(c) "warning",
    message = function(c) "message"
  )
}
show_condition(stop("!"))
#> [1] "error"
show_condition(warning("?!"))
#> [1] "warning"
show_condition(message("?"))
#> [1] "message"

# If no condition is captured, tryCatch returns the 
# value of the input
show_condition(10)
#> [1] 10
```

Is `c` a system variable? [Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052434/992999) others seems to use `e` in its place?

Comment: `c` is a balance between meaning and time spent typing. I use `e` to handle errors and `w` for warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `function(c) "error"` is just an anonymous function run by `tryCatch` in case its `code` argument raises an error.

An argument of class `condition` is passed to this anonymous function, and it allows you to get the `call` that raises the error, and the `message` generated by R. For example :

```
R> tryCatch(print(foobar), error=function(c) print(c$message))
[1] "objet 'foobar' introuvable"
```

As such, `c` here is just the name you give to the `condition` passed as an argument, and you can give it any name you want : `c`, `e` or even `deliciouspizza`.

For example :

```
R> tryCatch(print(foobar), error=function(rcatladies) print(rcatladies$call))
print(foobar)
```

Comment: thanks. So it all depends on the initial function creating (or returning - my terminology is probably wrong) an argument of the appropriate class. If I was using my own function (and hadn't been smart enough to return such an argument), then would the tryCatch method fail?

Comment: @drstevok Hmm no, it doesn't depend on your initial function. The anonymous function is called by `tryCatch` in case of error, warning, message, etc. It's `tryCatch` that creates the `condition` argument and passes it to the anonymous function you defined. Not sure I'm really clear here...

Comment: No, that helps ... and I think that is where I was getting confused. I couldn't work out where the `condition` argument was coming from.