# Error handling in R

Tags: r

I'm running a for loop to do Arima using R. My for loop will change the p,d,q value & run the arima & store the p-d-q value in a data frame. But in this process some p-d-q value throw errors & my for loop is getting stopped.I don't want my for loop to stop in middle without completing the complete loops. Is it possible to not interrupt my for loop & store all p-d-q value except the error?

Comment: Besides the straightforward `try` Ricardo proposed (which is all I've ever used), you may want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for `try`.  (or altenatively, `tryCatch`)

I'm assuming you are running something like this:

```
  for (p in ..)
    for (q in...)
  ...

  mod <- arima(x, c(p,d,q))
```

If so, simply change that last line to

```
  mod <- try(arima(x, c(p,d,q)), silent=TRUE)
 # the silent is optional
```

---

However, you are probably better off doing:

```
 pdq <- expand.grid(p, d, q)
 apply(pdq, 1, function(o) try(arima(x, o), silent=TRUE))
```

---

Lastly, make sure that you're not just fishing   http://xkcd.com/882/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ricardo. I'm using the following code after modifying what you suggested

Comment: Code is available at https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=FF431A41D367C7D9&id=FF431A41D367C7D9%21105    Still I'm using following error Error in fit$aic : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
2: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
3: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
4: In log(s2) : NaNs produced   Can you please help me to resolve the error?

Comment: the error is telling you that `$` doesn't work with `fit`.  I'm guessing you are assigning something wrong to fit.   Please understand that asking someone to sift through your code is a relatively tall order.  Instead, consider trying to trouble shoot it yourself and when you encounter a specific issue, narrow it down to the offending section or lines and then asking a concrete question about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ricardo. Narrowing down it further, What I'm doing is storing Arima result in fit & then using fit to get several outcome,like AIC,predict future response & calculate MAPE. Now when I'm putting fit=try(Arima(..),silent=T). it is handling Arima error but still it is throwung error as it is not getting proper value of fit for fit$aic. So my question is-> Can I put multiple line of codes inside "try" block? if so how? I tried separate try block for each line of code but I'm not getting the output in proper format