# catching an exception on R getGEO

Tags: r, error-handling

I am using R and the GEOQuery package for downloading a set of GEO profiles. For doing this I use the following instructions:

```
library(Biobase)
library(GEOquery)
gdsAcc<-getGEO('GDS1245',destdir=".")
```

which downloads the GDS1245.soft.gz in the specified directory.

The problem is that some GEO profiles have been removed, so when I use the above mentioned instructions in a loop and I came with something like:

```
gdsAcc<-getGEO('GDS450',destdir=".")
```

in the last case the profile GDS450 does not exist so it throws an error and the program stops. I would like to know how I can catch that error so that in case that the profile does not exist the program will continue looking for the other profiles.

My algorithm is something like:

```
for (i in 1:length_GEO_profiles){
    disease<-GEOname
    gdsName<-paste("GDS",disease,sep="")
    gdsAcc<-getGEO(gdsName,destdir=".")
}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `try` and `tryCatch`. Here's an example to get you started:

```
for(i in 1:3) { 
  if(i == 1)
    gdsAcc <- try(getGEO('GDS450',destdir="."))
  cat(i, "\n")
}
```

If you want to do something with the error, then use an `if` statement:

```
if(class(gdsAcc) == "try-error") cat("HELP")
```

**Related questions**

- [Exception handling in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r)
- [Equivalent of "throw" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608130/equivalent-of-throw-in-r)
- [catching an error and then branching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158780/r-catching-an-error-and-then-branching-logic)