# Get variables in error messages?

Tags: r, error-handling

Here is my code:

```
test <- function(y){
irisname <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species")
  if(y %in% irisname){
    print(y)
  } else{
    test <- function(...) stop("dummy error")
    test(y)
  }
}
> test("ds")
  Error in test(y) : dummy error
```

In the result: `"Error in test(y) : dummy error "`, I need "ds" in test("ds"), not test(y).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the argument right at the start of the function.  `match.arg` might come in handy, or you could print custom message and return NA.

**two updates below**

```
> test <- function(y)
  {
    if(!(y %in% names(iris))){
      message(sprintf('test("%s") is an error. "%s" not found in string', y, y))
      return(NA) ## stop all executions and exit the function
    }
    return(y)  ## ... continue
  }

> test("Sepal.Length")
# [1] "Sepal.Length"
> test("ds")
# test("ds") is an error. "ds" not found in string
# [1] NA
```

**Add/Edit :** Is there a reason why you're nesting a function when the function goes to `else`?  I removed it, and now get the following. It seems all you are doing is checking an argument, and end-users (and RAM) want to know immediately if they enter an incorrect default arguments.  Otherwise, you're calling up unnecessary jobs and using memory when you don't need to.

```
test <- function(y){
     irisname <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species")
     if(y %in% irisname){
         print(y)
     } else{
         stop("dummy error")
     }
 }
> test("ds")
# Error in test("ds") : dummy error
> test("Sepal.Length")
# [1] "Sepal.Length"
```

You could also use `pmatch`, rather than `match.arg`, since `match.arg` prints a default error.

```
> test2 <- function(x)
  {
      y <- pmatch(x, names(iris))
      if(is.na(y)) stop('dummy error')
      names(iris)[y]
  }
> test2("ds")
# Error in test2("ds") : dummy error
> test2("Sepal.Length")
# [1] "Sepal.Length"
```

Comment: My answer is closer to what the OP requested, but I think yours is closer to what they should be doing

Comment: Thanks Richard. Still, I need more help. The key to my question is how to get variables into Error message. There are two requests:1.Error message format: part1:part2. 2.in part 1,which i think R does it,the message will be Error in test("xx"). Notice "" !  Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @John, I'm a bit confused by that your comment. Notice in `> test("ds")` that `ds` is being quoted in both instances it occurs.  I'm not sure exactly what you want. If you could, please write a line with the exact error you want.

Comment: I believe @John wants *precisely* `Error in test("ds"): dummy error` -- as  I explain in my answer, I think this is going to be tough to achieve.  You can easily generate that string, but not in association with an error condition ...

Comment: Why can't they just use `stop('dummy error')`  upon argument checks?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm afraid they have some logic that they're not showing us for why they want `stop()` embedded within a further layer of function call, but it's impossible to tell from what they gave us.  This is why I said that I thought they should be following your structure (my answer attempts to keep the structure shown in their Q., but doesn't succeed in getting the precise error string they want).

Comment: Yeah, that way is really tough, but in reality users want the function to trigger an error immediately with incorrect default args.  Moving on... :)

Comment: @Richard,make it simple. All I want is putting values into variable y in Error message-Error in test(y) : dummy error in this format. And I think it can be done in a easy way, because I have seen this in some materials without any extra explanation. Maybe my code have some logic mistakes. I need to do this because my homework asked me to. And I will share exact process when I find the answer.Thanks any way.^_^

Comment: I have figured it out. 
simply BY
`if(y %in% irisname){`
`print(y)`
 `} else{`
 `stop("dummy error")`
 `}`
`> test("ds")`
`Error in test("ds") : dummy error` Thanks!@Ben @Richard

Comment: @John, glad you go it figured out.  Did you notice that my second function above is exactly that?

Comment: Yeah.Sorry,I didn't notice it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here variables in `stop(...)` would be great to answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

This almost does it (there's an extra colon ...), by using `call.=FALSE` to suppress the information about the call and hacking it into the error message.

**update**: added quotation marks to error #1; explained a bit more about why this problem is hard.

I don't know the structure of your code, but you are making life considerably harder for yourself by passing objects farther down into the structure.  It would be a lot easier to call `stop()` directly from within your first level, *or* to use the information carried in `y` directly within your error message.

```
test <- function(y,stop=FALSE){
   irisname <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width",
       "Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species")
   if (stop) stop(sprintf("premature stop: var %s",y))
   if(y %in% irisname){
       print(y)
   } else{
     test <- function(...) {
         stop(sprintf("in test(\"%s\"): dummy error",...),
               call.=FALSE)
     }
     test(y)
 }
}

test("junk")
## Error: in test("junk"): dummy error
test("junk",stop=TRUE)
## Error in test("junk", stop = TRUE) : premature stop: var junk
```

Getting rid of the spurious first colon in the output of `test("junk")` will be **considerably** harder, because the `Error:` string is hard-coded within R.  Your best bet is probably, somehow, to print your own custom error message and then stop silently, or recreate the behaviour of `stop()` without generating the message (see `?condition`: e.g. `return(invisible(simpleError("foo")))`).  However, you're going to have to jump through a lot of hoops to do this, and it will be hard to ensure that you get exactly the same behaviour that you would have with `stop()` (e.g. will the error message have been saved in the error-message buffer?)

What you want to do is probably possible by mucking around with R internals enough, but in my opinion so hard that it would be better to rethink the problem ...

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Still, I need more help. The key to my question is how to get variables into Error message. There are two requests:1.Error message format: part1:part2. 2.in part 1,which i think R does it,the message will be Error in test("xx"). Notice "" !  Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Ben,make it simple. All I want is putting values into variable y in Error message-Error in test(y) : dummy error in this format. And I think it can be done in a easy way, because i have seen this in some materials without any extra explanation. Maybe my code have some logic mistakes.I will share exact process when I find the answer.Thanks any way.^_^

Comment: I have figured it out. 
simply BY
`if(y %in% irisname){`
`print(y)`
 `} else{`
 `stop("dummy error")`
 `}`
`> test("ds")`
`Error in test("ds") : dummy error`Thanks!@Ben @Richard